# How to collapse expanded drop-down when click outside of it on the web page in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

We created Directive for expanding and collapsing bootstrap 4 nav-bar dropdown. Each time the user clicks on it, it is toggled, moves between the states of Expanded and Collapsed.  When expanded and the user navigates to another area page it remains expanded. How can it force it to collapse when clicking outside of the dropdown button area, on the other parts of the web page for example? 
Here is the directive:

**TS**

```
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }
        @HostBinding('class.show') isOpen = false;
        @HostListener('click') toogleOpen() {
            this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
            this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.toggle('show')
        }

      }
```

**HTML**

```
<li *ngIf="isLogged" class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto" appdropdown #r="appdropdown">
...
...
</li>
```

How to close opened drop down by clicking on the other parts of a web page as well?

Comment: See how ng-bootstrap does it, or... just use ng-bootstrap. https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.ts#L108. It is battle-tested, has a huge test coverage, a big user base, and a great documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**html**:

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)"></button>
```

**component** (**typeScript**):

```
public clicked: boolean = false;

public onClick(event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicked = true;
}

@HostListener('document:click', ['event'])
private clickedOutside(event): void {
    if (this.clicked) {
        this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.toggle('show')
    }
}
```

I hope my help is effective ツ

Comment: I will check it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch click events and check if it is clicked outside by adding this listener to your directive:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
public onClick(targetElement) {
    const clickedInside = this._el.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
        this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.remove('show');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can You explain how to implement this inside my above one? Should it be mixed or be below it?

Comment: You can add it as a property of your `directive`. Just place it -for example- after your constructor.

Comment: I will check it and let you know.